# 쭈꾸미: meaning "octopus"?

Tags: vocabulary, meaning

I'm watching Hotel del Luna, episode 6, and in that there are several lines containing the above word, eg:

나는 쭈꾸미 먹으러 가려고 나온 거야.

그렇게 차려 입고 이 밤에 쭈꾸미를 먹으러 가자고요? 이건 내가 쭈꾸미 먹으러 갈 때

차려고 사둔 귀걸이야.

In the English subtitles, 쭈꾸미 is translated as "octopus".  However, Google translates it as "zucchini", and it doesn't exist in the Sejong online dictionary, or in the Minjung Essence dictionary.

Can anyone give me a bit more information on this word?

Comment: Well, the Wikipedia entry for Amphioctopus fangsiao (webfoot octopus) actually has this Korean word, with pictures of stir-fried and grilled octopus.  How can a dictionary not have an entry for what seems to be quite a well-known food??? Sheesh!

Comment: I have never heard of someone using 쭈꾸미 to mean zucchini. If I saw a 쭈꾸미 restaurant, I would be expecting the seafood, not a squash.

Answer (score 1):

쭈꾸미 is supposed to be a nonstandard spelling (although many people pronounce it like this).  The correct spelling is 주꾸미, which explains why you might not see 쭈꾸미 in the dictionary (but some dictionaries, like Naver, do have an entry for it redirecting to 주꾸미).

Google Translate has it mixed up in a strange way.  It translates 쭈꾸미 to 'webfoot octopus" which is reasonable but 주꾸미 to 'zucchini' which is wrong.  Something must have gone wrong in its phrase database, haha.

Answer (score 1):

쭈꾸미 is defined as 'non standard' spelling of 주꾸미 in naver dictionary [here](https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koko/505479deff3c4af9a536ea39a05ef055) and [here](https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koko/6384876360ca4d8488bee7e893442c5d)

This could be the reason why you couldn't find it in your dictionary (please link). However I think I have seen this word in most mobile dictionary apps I have used, and this spelling is more common in use even in seafood restaurants

Google translate in this case is probably wrong as 쭈꾸미 and zucchini do not sound anything alike, and naver dictionary transliterates zucchini [thusly](https://en.dict.naver.com/#/entry/enko/44774170ca7246c3b5d118ce52ef4b2d), and translates 쭈꾸미 to English like [this](https://en.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koen/a8fab8348f474fe087fec0cb661aa8bd)

Answer (score 1):

쭈꾸미 is a kind of octopus that is much smaller than the usual octopus. (The usual octopus is 문어.) It has nothing to do with zucchini. In Korea, there are many restaurants that specialize in 쭈꾸미, but few in 문어. 쭈꾸미 restaurants sell usually mostly 쭈꾸미, while the restaurants that sell 문어 sell other seafoods. 쭈꾸미 restaurants usually have the word "쭈꾸미" in their name, but I have never seen a restaurant that contains the word 문어.